# Send a WS request for each URL in a list and map the responses to a new list

Tags: web-services, scala, http, playframework

I'm developing a REST server in Play with Scala, that at some point needs to request data at one or more other web services. Based on the responses from these services the server must compose a unified result to use later on.

**Example**:

Event C on `www.someplace.com` needs to be executed. In order to execute Event C, Event A on `www.anotherplace.com` and Event B on `www.athirdplace.com` must also be executed.

Event C has a `Seq(www.anotherplace.com, www.athirdplace.com)` from which I would like to iterate and send a WS request to each URL respectively to check wether B and C are executed.

It is assumed that a GET to these URLs returns either `true` or `false`

How do I collect the responses from each request (preferably combined to a list) and assert that each response is equal to `true`?

**EDIT**: An event may contain an arbitrary number of URL's. So I cant know beforehand how many WS requests i need to send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short Answer

You can use [`sequence`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future$@sequence[A,M[X]<:TraversableOnce[X]](in:M[scala.concurrent.Future[A]])(implicitcbf:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[M[scala.concurrent.Future[A]],A,M[A]],implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[M[A]]) method available on [`Future`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.concurrent.Future$) object.

For example:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future

val urls = Seq("www.anotherplace.com", "www.athirdplace.com")
val requests = urls.map(WS.url)
val futureResponses = Future.sequence(requests.map(_.get()))
```

#### Aggregated `Future`

Note that the type of `futureResponses` will be `Future[Seq[WSResponse]]`. Now you can work on the results:

```
futureResponses.map { responses =>
  responses.map { response =>
    val body = response.body
    // do something with response body
  }
}
```

#### More Details

From [ScalaDocs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future$@sequence[A,M[X]<:TraversableOnce[X]](in:M[scala.concurrent.Future[A]])(implicitcbf:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[M[scala.concurrent.Future[A]],A,M[A]],implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[M[A]]) of `sequence` method:

> Transforms a TraversableOnce[Future[A]] into a
>   Future[TraversableOnce[A]]. Useful for reducing many Futures into a
>   single Future.

Note that if any of the `Future`s you pass to `sequence` fails, the resulting `Future` will be failed as well. Only when all `Future`s are completed successfully the result will complete successfully. This is good for some purposes, especially if you want to send requests at the same time, no one after another.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [the documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaWS) and see if you can get their example to work.
Try something like this:

```
val futureResponse: Future[WSResponse] = for {
  responseOne <- WS.url(urlOne).get()
  responseTwo <- WS.url(responseOne.body).get()
  responseThree <- WS.url(responseTwo.body).get()
} yield responseOne && responseTwo && responseThree
```

You probably need to parse the response of your WebService since they (probably) won't return booleans, but you'll get the idea.

Comment: I've seen that pattern to send multiple requests, however it won't work since an Event can have an arbitrary number of URLs to check on. I'm sorry that wasn't clear, I'll add that to my first post. But thanks anyway!

Comment: Use `map` and/or `foldLeft` on the `Seq` and then use the result.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: On how to use map and fold Left? Those are functions of the standard scala collections. Just google them, there are plenty of examples.